# Как запретить записывать значение в клетку, если она уже занята

Tags: swift

Игра крестики-нолики. Как сделать так, чтобы нельзя было записать значение, если в клетке уже есть значение и она занята, что можно сделать. Вот что пока на данный момент реализовал, простите за кривой код я только учусь))

```
    enum Symbols: String {
    case x = "❌"
    case o = "⭕"
    case empty = "⬜"
}

class TicTacToe {
    var sizeFiled: Int
    var arr = [[Symbols]]()

    init(sizeField: Int) {
        self.sizeFiled = sizeField
        createField()
    }

    func createField() {
        for _ in 0..<sizeFiled {
            let arr2d = Array(repeating: Symbols.empty, count: sizeFiled)
            arr.append(arr2d)
        }
    }

    func printField() {
        print()
        for i in arr {
            var temp = ""
            for j in i {
                temp += j.rawValue
            }
            print(temp)
        }
    }

    func clearField() {
        print("\n")
        print("========== New Game ==========")
        for i in 0..<arr.count {
            for j in 0..<arr.count {
                arr[i][j] = Symbols.empty
            }
        }
    }

    subscript(x: Int, y: Int) -> Symbols? {
        get {
            let dict: Symbols? = (x < 0 || y < 0) || (x >= sizeFiled || y >= sizeFiled) ? nil : arr[y][x]
            return dict
        }
        set {
            if (x < 0 || y < 0) || (x >= sizeFiled || y >= sizeFiled) || (newValue == Symbols.empty) && (newValue == nil) {
                print("Position not found\n")
            } else {
                arr[y][x] = newValue!
            }
        }
    }
}

var obj = TicTacToe(sizeField: 3)
obj[1, 1] = .o
obj[2, 2] = .x
obj[0, 2] = .o
obj[2, 0] = .o
obj[3, 1] = .empty
obj.printField()

obj.clearField()
obj.printField()
obj[2, 2] = .x
obj[3, 3] = .x
obj.printField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, вам стоит немного поправить проверку условия при записи:

```swift
subscript(x: Int, y: Int) -> Symbols? {
    get {
        ...    
    }
    set {
        guard                               // Используем guard вместо if, чтобы было наглядней
            let newValue = newValue,        // Не пытаются записать nil вместо значения
            x >= 0 && y >= 0,               // Координаты должны быть положительные
            x < sizeFiled && y < sizeFiled, // Координаты не выходят за пределы поля
            newValue != .empty,             // Не пытаются записать пустое поле
            arr[x][y] == .empty             // Текущая клетка пустая
            else {                          // Возвращаем ошибку если хотя бы одно условие выше не выполнено
                print("Position not found\n")
                return
            }
        arr[y][x] = newValue                // Если всё хорошо, то записываем значение
    }
}
```